# How to query a sub documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help in writing a query which brings the attributes in a sub docment (Metrics).

My data layout is as follows.

DB = Ngcore

Collection = DTM

subcode (Document) ==> Validation (Document inside subcode) ==> Metrics (Document inside validation) ==> Code (String) , Default value (int32) , class (String)  (Attributes inside metrics docuemnt)

My query should return code,default & Class associated with metrics = 1110013

Thanks,

Comment: can you please post a sample document and a sample expected response? this would help anyone else help you

Comment: {
  "_id" : "1393641120998",
  "status" : "IN_PROGRESS",
  "variables" : {
    "DATA_LOAD_ID" : "1393641120998"},
  "id" : "1393641120998",
  "metrics" : { },
  "subProcess" : {
    "FILE_ARRIVAL" : {}],
      "rejectsPer" : 0.0,},
    "VALIDATION" : {
      "startDate" : new Date(""),
      "qaStatus" : "PEN",
      "code" : "VALID",
      "variables" : { }
        }],
      "totalAccepted" : 0,
      "metrics" : {
        "1110013" : {
          "variationsCount" : {
            "DEFAULT" : 17317},
          "code" : "1110013",
          "clazz" : "com.bl"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access sub-documents, like:

```
Ngcore.DTM.find({ 'Validation.Metrics': 11110013 })
```

Comment: IT DOESN`T RETURN ANY VALUES.

> db.dtm.find({ 'subProcess.VALIDATION.metrics': 1110013 })
>